# Verificar uptime do servidor com Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou fazendo várias requisições HTTP num determinado tempo e desejo verificar **apenas o status de retorno**. Existem paths que exigem o login na aplicação mas como é um script bem básico e **não é teste de interface** não acho necessário usar o `Zombie.js` ou `Nightwatch.js`

Há algum jeito de fazer essas requisições em áreas restritas? Não existe API, seria necessário autenticar login via form

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada [nessa pergunta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051393/node-js-how-to-check-status-of-a-url-within-a-http-request), talvez ajude. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solução 1

**Sem código de status**

Não sou programador Node.JS, mas acredito que um *ping* resolveria seu problema.

Uma rápida pesquisa no Google encontrei o pacote [net-ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-ping).

```
var ping = require ("net-ping");
var session = ping.createSession ();

session.pingHost (target, function (error, target) {
    if (error)
        console.log (target + ": " + error.toString ());
    else
        console.log (target + ": Alive");
});
```

**Obs.:** Essa solução não é muito eficiente para seu caso, pois o servidor pode estar ativo, mas o serviço pode ter caído.

---

### Solução 2

**Com código de status**

Encontrei um pacote que faz a requisição e exibe o código:

[Package Request](https://github.com/request/request)

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://pt.stackoverflow.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Mostra o HTML da página inicial do StackOverflow.
  }
});
```

Não é possível obter apenas o cabeçalho ou código de status em uma requisição HTTP, mesmo porque não é o cliente que controla isso.

A requisição é feita da seguinte forma:

> **Cliente:**
>   - Olá quero a página index.php
>   **Servidor:**
>   - Pois não, aqui está sua página
>
> > Cabeçalho: Status 200; Etc...
> >
> > ---
> >
> > Corpo da página index.php
>
> **Cliente:**
>   - Olá, agora quero a página akjshlahsdasd.html
>   **Servidor:**
>   - Desculpe, não a encontrei.
>
> > Cabeçalho: Status 404; Etc...
> >
> > ---
> >
> > Corpo página 404
>
> **Cliente:**
>   - Então me dê a página serviceInternal.php
>   **Servidor:**
>   - Desculpe, estamos com problemas técnicos
>
> > Cabeçalho: Status 500; Etc...
> >
> > ---
> >
> > Corpo página 500
>
> **Cliente:**
>   - Hmm, me dê então dados-banco.ini
>   **Servidor:**
>   - Sinto muito, você não pode acessar esse arquivo
>
> > Cabeçalho: Status 403; Etc...
> >
> > ---
> >
> > Corpo página 403

Note que até mesmo para erros de requisição/servidor é retornado o corpo de uma página HTML, isso só pode ser mudado nas configurações do próprio servidor.

### Solução 3

Uma terceira solução, seria verificar se a porta web está aberta, porém essa porta pode variar em alguns servidores. A porta padrão é `80`, outros servidores utilizam `8080`.

Com o pacote [node-portscanner](https://github.com/baalexander/node-portscanner) você pode verificar se a porta está aberta.

```
> var portscanner = require('portscanner')
undefined
> portscanner.checkPortStatus(443, 'www.google.com', console.log)
> null 'open'
> portscanner.checkPortStatus(80, 'www.google.com', console.log)
undefined
> null 'open'
```

**Obs.:** Assim como na primeira solução esta não é muito eficiente, pois o servidor pode estar ativo e a porta aberta, mas o serviço pode ter caído.

---

Receber apenas o status do servidor só é possível se você criar uma página vazia no servidor, assim você pode requisita-la para o teste da conexão, recebendo apenas o cabeçalho da requisição.

Mais detalhes sobre o protocolo HTTP:

1. [Entendendo um pouco mais sobre o protocolo HTTP](http://simplesideias.com.br/entendendo-um-pouco-mais-sobre-o-protocolo-http)
2. [Protocolo HTTP](http://cin.ufpe.br/~erp/DesenvWeb/aulas/http_servlet/http.pdf)

Comment: A ideia é saber que tipo de erro deu na requisição, esse "uptime" é estar no ar e ter retorno 200. Apesar disso, `net-ping` ainda não resolveria o problema de áreas que necessitam de autenticação correto?

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais, atualizei a resposta. ;)