# Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?

Tags: http, request

Os métodos HTTP são utilizados para enviar e receber dados do servidor, tais como o `GET` (recupera dados) e o `POST` (envia os dados).

Seguindo a definição acima da para entender muito bem a finalidade do `GET` e do `POST`, porem eu tenho uma dúvida pertinente a respeito de como o HTTP processa a requisição de acordo com o verbo HTTP.

## Dúvida

Como o protocolo HTTP processa (por baixo dos panos) as requisições, ou seja, como ocorre a comunicação cliente e servidor através dos métodos de requisição?

Comment: Só pra adiantar: o protocolo HTTP não processa nada. Ele só normatiza como é que os dados devem ser comunicados. Quem processa o HTTP é a aplicação.

Comment: Uma resposta no SO.pt que envolve o protocolo HTTP: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66765/8493 nela também tem 2 links para o assunto.

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é um “protocolo sem estado”, como o HTTP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119549/18246)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Antes de mais nada é bom entender o HTTP como uma série de convenções de formatos a serem usados sobre uma conexão TCP comum. Em princípio é um protocolo *stateless* no qual você basicamente envia um texto e recebe outro de volta.

Em outras palavras, o HTTP não processa nada, e sim define um formato. É responsabilidade da aplicação que atende ao pedido processar os dados, e fornecer uma resposta coerente com o protocolo.

A [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) mesmo tem uma definição razoável do HTTP, mas vou tentar evidenciar os pontos mais relevantes para a pergunta de maneira mais simples logo a seguir.

Se quiser se aprofundar na específicação depois de entender o básico, segue link para o **Consórcio W3**, que é o responsável por definir e regulamentar oficialmente o padrão:

> https://www.w3.org/Protocols/

### Formato

Uma requisição HTTP é em princípio um mero stream de texto, característica por este formato (cada linha da tabela é uma linha do texto, quebrada por CR + LF:

```
            | REQUISIÇÃO                      | RESPOSTA
------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------
CABEÇALHO   | METODO CAMINHO PROTOCOLO/VERSAO | PROTOCOLO/VERSAO STATUS
            | Cabeçalho 1: valor1             | Cabeçalho 1: valor1
            | Cabeçalho 2: valor2 ...         | Cabeçalho 2: valor2 ...
            | Cabeçalho N: valorN             | Cabeçalho N: valorN
linha vazia |                                 | 
CORPO       | DADOS DO PEDIDO                 | DADOS DA RESPOSTA
```

- O `MÉTODO` é o `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, mas não se limita a estes. Inclusive, você pode estender o protocolo e definir métodos específicos para a aplicação que está usando (e precisa fazer o método correspondente do lado do servidor).

  > [Quais são os métodos de requisição HTTP, e qual é a diferença entre eles?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9419/70)

  > [Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49322/70)

  > [Quando devo usar função GET e quando devo usar função POST?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118213/70)
- o `CAMINHO` é aquele que vem depois do URL. Seja só uma barra `/` ou seja um caminho para o recurso como `/blog/47894/como-fazer-amigos-e-influenciar-pessoas`. Pode incluir uma *query string*, como `?mode=json` ao final.

  Importante notar que as âncoras não fazem parte do caminho. Num endereço como `/index.html?order=date#details`, o caminho é apenas `/index.html?order=date`.
- o `PROTOCOLO/VERSAO` costumam ser `HTTP/1.1`, muito raramente `HTTP/1.0`, e agora vários sites *mainstream* trabalham com o `HTTP/2`.

  Sobre isto, tem alguns detalhes aqui:

  > [Quais as diferenças entre HTTP 1.1 vs HTTP 1.0?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153512/70)

#### Exemplificando

Quando você acessa no navegador um site como `www.exemplo.com.br`, seu navegador resolve o endereço (transforma `www.exemplo.com.br` num endereço de IP, usando DNS).

Em seguida, ele se conecta por TCP ao IP obtido, em princípio na porta 80 (que é a padrão do HTTP, sendo 443 a padrão do HTTPS). Uma vez conectado, ele vai enviar algo assim, textualmente:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.exemplo.com.br
```

e é só isso. Supondo que haja uma página no endereço requisitado, você vai receber algo assim de volta:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Length: 351
Connection: close

<html>...
```

Note que é quase a mesma coisa, só que na resposta em vez de você ter `METODO CAMINHO PROTOCOLO` você tem `PROTOCOLO STATUS DESCRICAO_DO_STATUS` na primeira linha.

### Métodos

Uma vez entendida a parte básica do protocolo, vamos ver o que muda se em vez de um `GET` tivermos um `POST`. No caso do `POST` temos algumas informações a mais a mandar, e como descrito acima, usamos uma linha em branco para separar o conteúdo do cabeçalho:

```
POST /formulariodeinscricao.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

nome=gato&senha=secret
```

Note que a palavra chave aqui é o `POST`, a informação da primeira linha, e no corpo da requisição (depois da linha em branco) temos os valores enviados. No caso usei o formato mais comum de formulários Web, o formato pode variar dependendo do caso.

Se fosse um envio de arquivo com `PUT` poderia muito bem ser assim:

```
PUT /upload.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

DADOS_DO_ARQUIVO..........
```

### Ferramenta de teste

Há algumas ferramentas online que ajudam muito a investigar e "debugar" requisições HTTP, uma delas é esta API, com vários endpoints, que mostram uma diversidade de informações, o que ajuda muito a testar separadamente a parte de envio e a de recebimento de sua aplicação:

> https://httpbin.org/

### Mais referências

> [O que é um "protocolo sem estado", como o HTTP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119549/70)

> https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 22):

## Protocolo

Como o Bacco já bem disse no comentário, protocolo é uma [especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101), então ele não processa qualquer coisa.

> pro·to·co·lo |ó|
> substantivo masculino
>
> 1. Formulário.
> 2. .Ata de conferências celebradas entre ministros plenipotenciários de diferentes nações, ou entre os membros de um congresso
>    internacional.
> 3. .Registro em que o escrivão do juízo relata o que se passou na audiência.
> 4. Regulamento que se observa em alguns .atos públicos.
>
> "protocolo", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/protocolo [consultado em
> 29-12-2016].

Pro nosso caso o que mais se encaixa é o quarto item. Ele é um conjunto de regras que indicam como a comunicação entre entidades computacionais vão "conversar". Eles precisam falar a mesma língua, precisam usar as palavras certas nos lugares certos para se entenderem de forma clara, completa e não ambígua. "Protocolo HTTP" é uma pleonasmo já que a sigla significa [HyperText Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) ou Protocolo de transferência em HiperTexto.

Especificamente o HTTP é algo que regula a camada de aplicação de redes usando tecnologias web. Essas regras são definidas pelo [World Wide Web Consortium](https://www.w3.org/).

O HTTP basicamente é um texto simples (HTTP 2 pode ser binário) com um cabeçalho dizendo o que é aquilo e depois um conteúdo que está querendo comunicar efetivamente (antes ele tinha que ser sempre texto, então conteúdo binário, como uma imagem, precisava ser convertido para texto). Isso já faz parte do que diz o protocolo. O que esse cabeçalho deve ter, o que é obrigatório, o que é opcional, o que deve ser em uma requisição e o que deve ser em uma resposta, até mesmo definir esses termos, tudo isso está no protocolo. Entre as regras há a indicação do que fazer com os casos de erros, o formato de cada parte, etc.

Claro que entre essas regras está o que fazer com cada campo, cada verbo, os códigos de erro, etc.

[Uma lista de campos regulados está na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Exemplo de cabeçalho de requisição:

```
GET /hello.htm HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: www.seusite.com
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Note que o protocolo não quer saber nada de como a comunicação em si está sendo feita, é problema de outro protocolo que provavelmente vai encapsular o pacote HTTP. O HTTP só cuida disso que tá aí e aqui embaixo.

Exemplo de resposta HTTP:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 29 Dec 2016 12:02:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32)
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Dec 2016 13:16:38 GMT
Content-Length: 88
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: Closed

<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

## Aplicação

Uma aplicação que queria se conformar com o HTTP deve seguir essas regras. Em alguns casos a aplicação e o ambiente onde ela roda precisam processar outros protocolos em camadas diferentes, isso é o chamado [modelo OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

A aplicação recebe esse "texto" e o processa. Ou seja, ele faz um [*parsing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) do que encontra ali e decide o que fazer com a informação encontrada (o que vem a ser a [análise semântica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_analysis_(linguistics))). Há também o envio de "texto", aí ele apenas tem que montá-lo de acordo com as regras, colocar cada coisa na ordem necessárias, pulando linha, tendo os textos esperados, etc. Isso será processado do outro lado. Em geral tem um cliente que faz as requisições e um servidor que fornece as respostas.

Como a aplicação fará isso é problema dela, ela só precisa respeitar as regras.

Cabem perguntas mais específicas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 9):

HTTP é o modelo teórico para comunicação de sistemas de hipertexto. Porcamente comparando, ele é uma lista de regras para que dois estrangeiros possam ter uma comunicação bem sucedida. 
A comunicação total é toda arquitetada em um modelo chamado OSI (Open Systems Interconnection). HTTP acredito que atue na terceira camada (me corrijam).

- 7 Camada de aplicação;
- 6 Camada de apresentação;
- 5 Camada de sessão;
- 4 Camada de transporte;
- 3 Camada de rede;
- 2 Camada de enlace de
  dados;
- 1 Camada física.

Sua pergunta dá a entender dois caminhos:

- 1) Como o hardware processa a comunicação dos dados?
- 2) Como o servidor recebe dados que o sistema operacional recebe das requisições?

A primeira pergunta é uma questão de engenharia elétrica, e acredito não fazer parte da cultura do stack overflow. A segunda pergunta, está relacionada ao entendimento de como funciona o sistema operacional. 
Existe o kernel, que tem comunicação mais próxima com o hardware, e os programas auxiliares, que de fato tornam o sistema 'operativo'. O kernel recebe os dados do hardware, processa em seus programas auxiliares, até chegar a sétima camada do modelo OSI. Os dados são organizados em pacotes, que possui um cabeçalho (header) com informações de destino e origem. Aqui nesse momento é que as requisições GET/POSTs são aprovados ou recusados os pedidos por motivos físicos.  Aprovação ou recusa de dados via GET/POSTs por motivos lógicos, devem ocorrer da quinta camada em diante. Por essa delicada e direta relação, que um sistema operacional é relevante para a segurança.
Se usei algum conceito não genuíno do ponto de vista da engenharia, foi para ser didático. Estejam a vontade para edições e correções.

Leitura recomendada:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_OSI

Comment: Nope, `http` é na aplicação... E ficou meio confuso essa mistura de hardware, kernel, bom pelo menos para mim...

Comment: Imagine que você esteja usando um programa que se comunica com o teclado. Mesmo uma tarefa simples como teclar, tem um software para interpretar essa ação. Agora imagine que um programa queira acessar um mesmo endereço de memória desse teclado, e até apagasse  ele. Teríamos um problema. Por isso, é desejável que o O.S. tenha mais acesso ao hardware do que os aplicativos. Algumas linguagens de alto nível usam ponteiros para criar endereço de memória. Em linguagens de montagem e de baixo nível as coisas podem ficar bem cabeludas.

Comment: O que quis dizer é que é desnecessário citar o hardware, uma vez que a comunicação ocorre na aplicação, tanto o `request` quanto o `response` ocorrem na aplicação, para chegar a esse momento do processo presume-se que o S.O. já fez a parte dele...

Comment: Citei o hardware porque a pergunta do autor não foi muito específica. Quando ele diz "por debaixo dos panos", dá múltiplas interpretações. Dá entender que ele tem curiosidade para saber o que acontece nas camadas mais baixas. Por ele falar em "processar" requisições http, ele pode ter tido uma falsa impressão do papel do protocolo http, achando que atua nas camadas mais baixas. Eu mesmo achei que atuasse na quinta camada, e você me corrigiu. Ele sabendo que o papel do hardware e do O.S., pode facilitar o entendimento de que o http não processa nada.