# Página imprimindo script do PHP

Tags: php

A página está imprimindo as próprias linhas de código php a partir da seguinte linha:

```
5189.82){
```

Código inteiro:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
    body{padding: 0px; margin: 0px; text-align: center;}
    ul{list-style: none;}
    table{max-width: 260px;}
    table td{width: 120px; height: 20px; text-align: right;}
    #resultados{position: relative;}
    #mobi li{display: inline; font-size: 11pt; margin-right: 15px;}
    #esquerda{float: left; margin-left: 400px; text-align: right;}
    #esquerda ul{margin-top: 0px;}
    #esquerda li{margin-bottom: 12px;}
    #direita{float: right; margin-right: 540px; margin-top: -8px;}
    #lucro{position: absolute; margin-left: 600px; margin-top: 160px; background-color: #FFFF00; width: 200px; height: 70px; border: 1px solid black; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;}
    .grupoUm{background-color: #D3D3D3; border: 2px solid #BEBEBE;}
    .grupoDois{border: 3px solid #2F4F4F;}
</style>
<?php
    $bonus = $_POST['bonus'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $taxaDocSemMobi = 3;

    $taxaDocComMobi = 3.99;

    $inssSemMOBI;
    if($bonus + $taxaDocSemMobi > 5189.82){
        $inssSemMOBI = 570.88;
    }
    else{
        $inssSemMOBI = ($bonus - $taxaDocSemMobi) * 11 / 100;
    }

    $inssComMOBI = 44;

    $receitaTributavelAutonomo = $bonus - $taxaDocSemMobi - $inssSemMOBI;
    $irrfAutonomo;
    $irrfDeducao;
    if($receitaTributavelAutonomo < 1904.98){
        $irrfAutonomo = 0;
        $irrfDeducao = 0;
    }
    else if($receitaTributavelAutonomo > 1903.98 && $receitaTributavelAutonomo < 2827.65){
        $irrfAutonomo = 7.5;
        $irrfDeducao = 142.8;
    }
    else if($receitaTributavelAutonomo > 2826.65 && $receitaTributavelAutonomo < 3752.05){
        $irrfAutonomo = 15;
        $irrfDeducao = 354.8;
    }
    else if($receitaTributavelAutonomo > 3751.05 && $receitaTributavelAutonomo < 4665.68){
        $irrfAutonomo = 22.5;
        $irrfDeducao = 636.13;
    }
    else{
        $irrfAutonomo = 27.5;
        $irrfDeducao = 869.36;
    }
    $irrfSemMOBI = $receitaTributavelAutonomo * $irrfAutonomo / 100 - $irrfDeducao;

    $rendaBruta = $bonus * 12;
    $receitaTributavel = $rendaBruta * (1 - (1 * 32 / 100));
    $porc20Simplificado = $receitaTributavel * 0.8;
    $irrfMEI;
    $irrfMEIDeducao;
    if($porc20Simplificado < 22847.77){
        $irrfMEI = 0;
        $irrfMEIDeducao = 0;
    }
    else if($porc20Simplificado > 22847.76 && $porc20Simplificado < 33919.81){
        $irrfMEI = 7.5;
        $irrfMEIDeducao = 1713.58;
    }
    else if($porc20Simplificado > 33919.80 && $porc20Simplificado < 45012.61){
        $irrfMEI = 15;
        $irrfMEIDeducao = 4257.57;
    }
    else if($porc20Simplificado > 45012.60 && $porc20Simplificado < 55976.17){
        $irrfMEI = 22.5;
        $irrfMEIDeducao = 7633.51;
    }
    else{
        $irrfMEI = 27.5;
        $irrfMEIDeducao = 10432.32;
    }
    $irrfComMOBI = ($porc20Simplificado * $irrfMEI / 100 - $irrfMEIDeducao) / 12;

    $descontaISS = true;
    $issSemMOBI;
    if($descontaISS == true){
        $issSemMOBI = $bonus * 5 / 100;
    }
    else{
        $issSemMOBI = 0;
    }

    $issComMOBI = 5;

    $bonusLiquidoSemMOBI = $bonus - $taxaDocSemMobi - $inssSemMOBI - $irrfSemMOBI - $issSemMOBI;

    $bonusLiquidoComMOBI = $bonus - $taxaDocComMobi - $inssComMOBI - $irrfComMOBI - $issComMOBI;

    $lucro = $bonusLiquidoComMOBI - $bonusLiquidoSemMOBI;
  ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="resultados">
    <ul id="mobi">
        <li>Sem conta.MOBI</li>
        <li><b>Com conta.MOBI</b></li>
    </ul>
<div id="esquerda"> 
    <ul>
        <li>Taxa DOC/Boleto</li>
        <li>INSS</li>
        <li>IRRF</li>
        <li>ISS</li>
        <li>Bônus Líquido</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="direita">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="grupoUm" id="taxaSemMOBI"><?php echo $taxaDocSemMobi ?></td>
            <td class="grupoDois" id="taxaComMOBI"><?php echo $taxaDocComMobi ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="grupoUm" id="inssSemMOBI"><?php echo $inssSemMOBI ?></td>
            <td class="grupoDois" id="inssComMOBI"><?php echo $inssComMOBI ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="grupoUm" id="irrfSemMOBI"><?php echo $irrfSemMOBI ?></td>
            <td class="grupoDois" id="irrfComMOBI"><?php echo $irrfComMOBI ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="grupoUm" id="issSemMOBI"><?php echo $issSemMOBI ?></td>
            <td class="grupoDois" id="issComMOBI"><?php echo $issComMOBI ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="grupoUm" id="bonusLiquidoSemMOBI"><?php echo $bonusLiquidoSemMOBI ?></td>
            <td class="grupoDois" id="bonusLiquidoComMOBI"><?php echo $bonusLiquidoComMOBI ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id = "lucro">
    Você receberá a mais:
    <b><h2 id = "valor"><?php echo $lucro ?></h2></b>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual é a url que vc acessa no navegador?

Comment: file:///C:/wamp/www/meixautonomoresultados.php

Comment: Na barra de endereço quando vc digita `file:///` está dizendo para acessar o arquivo diretamente, sem passar pelo interpretador do PHP, o certo é usar o `http://localhost/projeto/index.php` ou só `localhost/projeto/index.php`. Tem mais detalhes no link lá em cima da pergunta.

Comment: Tem essa outra pergunta (bem interessante) [Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174116/91) que dá uma visão geral do que acontece.

Comment: Aparente o código está certo. Provavelmente o PHP não está executando. Para ter certeza. Acessa a página e utilize as teclas CTRL+U e verifique se o código fonte recebido pelo browser é igual ao código original. Se for, o teu problema será descobrir o que está errado com teu servidor.