# Qual é a finalidade da função "header()"?

Tags: php, http

Na minha pergunta sobre o [protocolo HTTP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174116/como-o-protocolo-http-processa-as-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es) entendi que as requisições HTTP possui um formato que é descrito pelo próprio protocolo.

Entretanto, em PHP existe uma função que envia dados para o HTTP que é a função `header()` e eu não compreendi muito bem a sua finalidade, mesmo lendo o manual fiquei com dúvidas que podem ser esclarecidas com uma resposta canônica.

## Dúvidas

1. Qual é a finalidade da função `header()`?
2. A função `header()` possui alguma relação com o protocolo HTTP?
3. Quando a função `header()` deve ser utilizada?

<sup>Para facilitar melhor meu entendimento, eu gostaria de exemplos práticos caso seja possível.</sup>

Comment: O Cabeçalho de uma requisição/resposta HTTP é uma lista de chave/valor. Basicamente essa função adiciona novos valores, ou atualizam valores que já existe no cabeçalho da resposta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Qual é a finalidade da função header()?

Justamente montar um cabeçalho para o pacote HTTP que será transmitido naquela requisição. Por padrão ele gera um básico com o mínimo necessário, se você deseja personalizar pode usar essa função.

> A função header() possui alguma relação com o protocolo HTTP?

Totalmente, só faz sentido para isso.

> Quando a função header() deve ser utilizada?

Sempre que precisar fazer algo que não é o comum. Pode enviar um erro específico (`HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found`), pode indicar o tipo de conteúdo que será enviada (`Content-Type`), expiração (`Expires`), trabalhar com autenticação (`WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="realm"`), e talvez uma das mais usadas na prática, redirecionar para outro conteúdo (`location`). Mas qualquer coisa que permita o protocolo pode ser usado, até mesmo extensões do cabeçalho.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Exemplos:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://www.example.com');

header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
header('Retry-After: 60');

header('Content-Type: image/png');

header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');
header ('Pragma: no-cache');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode($file));   
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Type: application/download');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');            
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
echo file_get_contents($file);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="plain_text_file.txt"');

header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="The Realm"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/Header.php).

Answer (score 5):

O Cabeçalho de uma requisição/resposta HTTP é uma lista de chave/valor.

1 - Basicamente essa função permite adicionar valores, ou atualizar valores que já existe no cabeçalho da resposta por padrão(definidas pelo servidor).

2 - Sim, a função dela é permitir editar o cabeçalho de uma resposta HTTP.

3 - Quando você precisar inserir/alterar algum valor do cabeçalho de resposta. Isso pode ser útil para diversas coisas, como por exemplo: Forçar redirecionamento; Forçar download do conteúdo; Retornar um status especifico; etc.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php

Answer (score 2):

Apenas reforçando o que já foi dito, a função `header` monta o cabeçalho de resposta http que será enviado para o browser.

Um adendo em relação à função `header` é que ela possui um segundo parâmetro opcional, chamado `$replace`. Se você utilizado como `false`, o cabeçalho poderá se repetir, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate');
header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM', false);
```