# Em que linguagem o HTTP foi escrito quando implementado na Web?

Tags: html, http

Quero saber em qual linguagem o HTTP foi desenvolvido.

Comment: HTTP é um protocolo, foi escrito em inglês :)

Answer (score 26):

Inglês. Protocolos são [especificações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101), portanto não são escritos em linguagens de programação. Implementações de protocolos podem ser escritos em [linguagens de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) e podem ser escritos em quaisquer linguagens.

Talvez ache alguma tradução para português, mas é irrelevante. Quem vai implementar isso precisa saber inglês. Acho que todo programador deveria conhecer o protocolo antes de usar, mas na prática só os que sabem inglês costumam se preocupar com esse tipo de coisa.

Especificações existem porque não deve haver uma forma única de fazer as coisas, apenas deve haver regras claras e não ambíguas. Todas implementações devem conversar sem problemas se forem programadas corretamente dentro da especificação.

Protocolos são regras de como algo deve ocorrer, em geral como algo deve se comunicar.

Como normalmente essa implementação é um software básico rodando embaixo de aplicações e não pode influir muito no tempo de processamento é comum usar linguagens que podem dar a melhor performance possível se o programador souber muito o que está fazendo. Então C e C++ são linguagens onde se costuma fazer implementações para depois serem usadas em outras linguagens. Mas nada impede, e de fato hoje há muito uso de outras linguagens, escrever em linguagens de mais alto nível. A perda de performance não será ruim se o código for bem feito. Afinal linguagens de programação não possuem velocidade, apenas facilitam ou não o programador obter a melhor possível.

Existem centenas, talvez milhares de implementações, algumas só como experimento. Deve existir pelo menos uma implementação em cada linguagem *mainstream* e também tem em muitas outras de nicho.

Essas implementações fazem essas regras especificadas acontecerem.

[Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174116/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).