# Como posso criar meu próprio protocolo assim como o HTTP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Veja esse código abaixo. Ele cria um servidor com o Node.js. Mas, se eu alterar o var http para exemplo: `var xyz = require ("xyz"), var server = xyz.createserver`... dá erro.

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  response.write("<!DOCTYPE "html">");
  response.write("<html>");
  response.write("<head>");
  response.write("<title>Hello World Page</title>");
  response.write("</head>");
  response.write("<body>");
  response.write("Hello World!");
  response.write("</body>");
  response.write("</html>");
  response.end();
});

server.listen(80);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

Comment: Talvez porque criar um protocolo é muito além do que apenas renomeá-lo? Quando você usa o `require` você está "chamando um arquivo", é como se você informasse ["vou precisar usar essa biblioteca"](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3954ea9f41b187915c4812ff6f360276bc94028c/doc/api/http.md). Então passa a usar o que ele oferece, que é um conjunto de funções que _alguém_ desenvolveu e você utiliza.  Quando você usa `xyz` ele não existe, portanto você não pode usar. Se você realmente quer criar um novo protocolo acredito que terá um longo caminho para isso.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta. Sou novo no node.js e tals. Ainda preciso saber muita coisa.

Comment: Existem vários níveis e protocolo. Inclusive, existem protocolos sobre protocolos. O próprio TCP/IP (boa barte da nossa internet atual) funciona sobre 5 camadas principais de protocolo: 1. camada física; 2. cama da de enlace/salto (ethernet/ATM); 3. camada de rede (IP); 4. camada de transporte (TCP/UDP); 5. camada de aplicação (HTTP/FTP/SSH etc). Eu particularmente já escrevi alguns protocolos sobre o HTTP (uso HTTP como base) e, também, tive de fazer a engenharia reversa de um protocolo não documentado (lá do trabalho) que funcionava diretamente sobre TCP. Posso responder com isso, se desejar

Comment: Adendo ao meu comentário: quando li o título da pergunta, interpretei como sendo sobre protocolos de maneira genérica, não havia me atentado ao fato de estar ligado com `node.js`.

Comment: @teves-rei A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Com muito estudo dos fundamentos da computação.

Bom, simplificadamente, escreve em um papel o que deseja que ele faça, quais operações, como é o formato das mensagens, os erros, como lidar com cada situação. Já terá um protocolo.

Depois que [especificou precisa implementá-lo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101).

Mas, não! Se nem os programadores mais experientes ficam criando protocolos a não ser em caso de extrema necessidade, não tente fazer isto em casa, nem com supervisão de adultos :)

Veja: [Em que linguagem o HTTP foi escrito?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177519/101).